# Apache mod_rewrite does not work with FastCGI

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, fastcgi, mod-proxy

I am trying to configure Apache with HHVM. As part of this, I need to configure rewrite rules. I have started HHVM as a daemon in FastCGI mode. I have enabled Apache modules `mod_proxy`, `mod_proxy_fcgi`, and `mod_rewrite`.

First, without `mod_rewrite`, I have this virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /app
  ProxyPass / fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/app/
</VirtualHost>
```

I have a file `/app/foo.php` which looks like this:

```
<?php echo "HELLO\n";
```

And as such I can access it using:

```
$ curl http://localhost/foo.php
HELLO
```

Now, after configuring my rewrite rules:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /app
  ProxyPass / fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/app/

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo.php
</VirtualHost>
```

What I expect to happen is that all requests now result in execution of the `foo.php` file, outputting `HELLO`.

However, what does happen is that I am given an HTTP 403, not just for requests to `/foo.php`, but for any request:

```
$ curl http://localhost/foo.php
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /foo.php
on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>

$ curl http://localhost/blah
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /blah
on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

The Apache error log shows me:

```
$ tail -2 /var/log/apache2/error.log 
[Fri Apr 11 21:30:20.645439 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 5090:tid 140114499983104] [client 127.0.0.1:39056] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /app/foo.php
[Fri Apr 11 21:30:23.281610 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 5090:tid 140114616588032] [client 127.0.0.1:39057] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /app/foo.php
```

Following this, I set directory access permissions:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /app
  ProxyPass / fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/app/

  <Directory /app>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo.php
</VirtualHost>
```

And now Apache serves the plain `/app/foo.php` file:

```
$ curl http://localhost/blah
<?php

echo "HELLO\n";
```

That is, now it appears to respect the rewrite rules, but is now ignoring the `ProxyPass` rule.

How do I get these to work together?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one out: use `ProxyPassMatch`, and don't bother with `mod_rewrite`.

Like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /app

  ProxyPassMatch ^.*$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/app/foo.php

  <Directory /app>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and didn't have the luxury of not using mod_rewrite.
Turns out there is a conflict between mod_geoip and mod_rewrite if the mod_geoip option 'GeoIPScanProxyHeaders' is set to 'On' at the same time that  'mod_remoteip' is enabled.

'GeoIPScanProxyHeaders' is a setting for obtaining the client IP address for use by 'mod_geoip'. It turns out that **the mod_geoip option,'GeoIPScanProxyHeaders', should not be enabled on Apache 2.4 if 'mod_remoteip' is loaded**. 'mod_remoteip' should be preferred and 'mod_geoip' will use the findings of 'mod_remoteip'.